# Using zipfile.is_zipfile on zips embeded within zips

Tags: python, zip

is_zipfile on a file correctly identifies zip files. But when working on a file-like object generated by zipfile.open it does not. Is there any way to get this to work, or must I extract the file to a temporary location before use?

```
import zipfile

file = open(r'c:\temp\test.xlsx', 'rb')
if zipfile.is_zipfile(file): # only works with native files, not file-like
    print('Zip') # this line is executed, as expected
else:
    print('Not zip')

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(r'c:\temp\test.zip', 'rb'))
file = zip.open('test.xlsx', 'r')
if zipfile.is_zipfile(file): # only works with native files, not file-like
    print('Zip')
else:
    print('Not zip') # this line is executed. WHY?
```

My output is:

```
Zip
Not zip
```

My expected result is that both should test as a zip file. It works for a native file, but not as part of a zip file.

Comment: not sure what you mean by processed. zipfile.is_zipfile according to the docs checks if the magic number evaluates as zip file, so probably your files differ in that. Maybe you can explain differently what you really want to achieve

Comment: Shouldn't you open the internal files as binary with 'rb', and you are testing whether they are a (binary) zipfile?

Comment: @user3732793
`zipfile.is_zipfile(file)` = true if `file=open('test.xlsx', 'rb')`.
`zipfile.is_zipfile(file)` = false if `file=zipfile.open('test.xlsx', 'r')`.
The test.xslx is the same data in both cases. I want the second response to evaluate to the same as the first.

Comment: @9769953 zipfile.open cannot take 'rb' its only options are 'r' and 'w'.

Comment: I've simplified the example. Hopefully clearer now.

Comment: sorry I am not deep enough into that. I would assume rb is getting back all the bytes of the file and therefore the magic byte can be read. If absend it is always false. As 9769953 metioned you probably always should use rb. Try with other files. E.g. just text files in the zip

Comment: Text files appear to read correctly. And as I would expect is_zipfile returns false for a text file.
I've found a workaround by by reading the file-like zipfile.open into memory, and using stringIO to turn that into a file-like to pass to is_zipfile, and then it all works. But it's pretty clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer / fix, but a workaround is to load the data into memory.

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(r'c:\temp\test.zip', 'rb'))
file = zip.open('test.xlsx', 'r')
data = file.read()
if zipfile.is_zipfile(StringIO.StringIO(data)):
    print('Zip')
else:
    print('Not zip')
```

It appears that the file-like produced by zipfile.open is not file-like enough for zipfile.is_zipfile to make use of.